# No api key after npm login for travis

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

According to: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/
You should see an api key after `npm login`. But after I do `npm login` (or `npm adduser`) and and `cat .npmrc` there is nothing with an api key.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Same problem here... any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

<del>Seems like the npm "api key" is nothing else than your npm username and password, divided by colon and base64-encoded.</del>

<del>So you can just do `echo -n "username:password" | base64` or use something like https://www.base64encode.org/.</del>

<del>Don't forget to use `travis encrypt` on that key. Easiest way to generate npm deploy is using `travis setup npm`, follow the dialog and paste the generated base64 key.</del>

#### The npm registry has recently switched from using password-based credentials to using session tokens.

After a `npm adduser`/`npm login`, you should have an entry like this in your `~/.npmrc`:

```
registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=THIS-IS-YOUR-API-KEY
```

You can paste this key during `travis setup npm` or directly set the value:

```
travis encrypt --add deploy.api_key YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, instead of manually encrypting your API key (and potentially getting it copied in your shell history (that's a security hazard)), you can just use:

```
travis setup npm
```

and this will ask you various question like you email, your api key (that you can paste here; it will get changed to '****'), and additional useful questions like do you want to publish only tagged commits, etc.

You can find your api key in your `.npmrc` file, as @simbo described.

Comment: Please note that if you are using Travis Pro that you should use `travis setup npm --com`.